# How to pass variable from view to controller using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass the variable from view file to **include_player_id** in controller file using ajax and execute the function. Here is what I have in hand.

Please help me on this. I spent days to make it but I am not successful in ajax.

**View.php**

```
<p><?php echo $ticket->last_name ?></p>
<input type="submit" class="btn-primary" value="<?php echo lang("ctn_474") ?>">
```

**Controller.php**

```
function sendMessage(){
    $content = array(
        "en" => 'Message'
        );

    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX",
        'include_player_ids' => array("XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX"),
        'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
        'large_icon' =>"ic_launcher_round.png",
        'contents' => $content
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);
print("\nJSON sent:\n");
print($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                               'Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

$response = sendMessage();
$return["allresponses"] = $response;
$return = json_encode( $return);
print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
print($return);
print("\n");
```

**I believe I need something like that**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function($){
    $(".btn-primary").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          datatype:"json",
          url: BASE_URL+"/application/controllers/Ticket.php",
          data: {
            'data':<?php echo $ticket->last_name ?>
          },
          contentType:'Text',
          processData: false,              
          error: function(response) {console.log('ERROR '+Object.keys(response)); },
          success: function(response) {
              console.log(response)

          }});

        return false;
    });  
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's the question? What is not working?

Comment: @Alex I tried many ajax examples from this site but not successful

Comment: Please explain what is NOT working. What is the behavior you like to achieve? Also, you don't use AJAX at all - you make HTTP requests.

Comment: @Alex I am trying to pass ECHO to controller file onClickButton

Comment: @Alex I updated the question

Comment: @Alex I thought you could end my search during the last few days

Comment: @Alex The problem is the variable is not passing to controller and the push notification is not delivered

Comment: What do you meed with "the variable is not passing"? There are a lot of variables ;-). Things to test: 1: Can you call your controller? 2: Do you get a valid response?

Comment: @Alex Yes a let of variables :)) By the way the all functions in controller are working with no bug.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for edition your post and providing the needed information. Let's assume you have a working HTTP Endpoint (GET) under `BASE_URL+"/application/controllers/Ticket.php"` (you can verify that it's working if you call the given URL in your browser).

Let's also assume that your `sendMessage()` function works like expected and does not contains bugs. I'd suggest you alter your `Controller.php` to something like this for testing purpose:

```
// static values, so we can be sure we get a predictable result for testing
$response = array['test1', 'test2'];
// rename the variable, return is a keyword and could cause problems
$result["allresponses"] = $response;
$json_result = json_encode( $result);
// comment this line, it will break the JSON.parse
// print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
// echo is just fine
echo $json_result;
// comment this line, it's not necessary
// print("\n");
```

Now try to call your controller under the given URI in your browser. If everything works fine you should see something like this:

> {"allresponses": ["test1", "test2"]}

as result in your browser.

Let's come to the HTML, JS part.

Your button should look like this :

```
// make this a button not submit - submit is for sending forms
// give the button an ID
<input type="button" class="btn-primary" id="myCoolButton" value="Click me"></input>
```

And your script could look like:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function($){
    // bind the function to the ID, otherwise all primary buttons would perform this function
    $("#myCoolButton").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
          // it's a GET endpoint as far as I understand your code, POST if creating new ressources
          type: "GET",
          datatype:"json",
          // enter your working endpoint URL here (the one you tested in your browser)
          url: BASE_URL+"/application/controllers/Ticket.php",         
          error: function(response) {console.log('ERROR '+Object.keys(response)); },
          success: function(response) {
              console.log(response)
          }});

        return false;
    });  
});
</script>
```

HTH

Comment: Give me some minutes to test it

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '$return' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: I altered my answer, have look to the controller

Comment: Message: syntax error, unexpected '$return' (T_VARIABLE)